# Python - Associate Numerical value to Categorical value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numeric, categorical-data

I have an excel file with a column like this:

[image]

Each level is assigned an numerical value where beginner = 1, intermediate = 4, advanced = 10, genius = 20, insane = 50.

Is there a way to associate the levels numerical value with its categorical value in a pandas data frame without changing it?

I know that I can just add another column but I was curious if there was such way to do this type of association so the dataframe will display the levels name "Beginner, Intermediate.." but if I want to use the numerical value for data analysis I can call the cell and it will recognise its numerical value.

Comment: You need to add an extra column or make a dictionary mapping level:integer

Answer (score 0):

Create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html) and use the values in your analysis:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

num_dict = {'beginner': 1, 'intermediate': 4, 'advanced': 10, 'genius':20, 
            'insane': 50}
test_data = np.vstack([[key, 1, 3] for key in num_dict.keys()])
test_data
```

```
array([['beginner', '1', '3'],
       ['intermediate', '1', '3'],
       ['advanced', '1', '3'],
       ['genius', '1', '3'],
       ['insane', '1', '3']], dtype='<U21')
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=['wanted', 'e', 'i'], index=range(len(num_dict.keys())))
df
```

|  | wanted | e | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | beginner | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | intermediate | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | advanced | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | genius | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | insane | 1 | 3 |

```
num_dict[df['wanted'][0]]

1
```

or use [`map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to along the whole column...

```
df['wanted'].map(num_dict)
```

|  | wanted |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 50 |

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the values with replace method.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
 
# replacing values
df['Level'].replace(['beginner', 'intermediate', 'advanced', 'genius', 'insane' ],
                        [1, 4, 10, 20, 50], inplace=True)
```

But since you don't want to change the dataframe, you can just map the values and
get copy of dataframe and perform your analysis.

```py
# mapping values
dict_map = {"beginner":1,
            "intermediate":4,
            "advanced":10,
            "genius":20,
            "insane":50}

copy_df = df['Level'].map(dict_map)
```